# Powershell substring matching of command output

Tags: powershell

Powershell 5.1.

I'm collecting the multi-line output of a command and trying to parse each line as a string, but it fails, and I cannot find the reason why.  What is the fundamental concept that I'm missing?

```
PS $x = wsl -l -v
PS $x[4]
  DistroName      Stopped     2
PS $x[4].Length
71
PS $x[4] -match "Stopped"
False
PS $z = "    DistroName      Stopped     2"
PS $z -match "Stopped"
True
PS $z.Length
36
```

Clearly there is something "extra" in the output from the command, but I can't figure out how to get rid of it.  `.Trim()` doesn't work.

------ Update ---------------------

```
PS $x[4].GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

------------ Solution -----------------

Thank you @Santiago Squarzon!
Running `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode` and then collecting the information did the trick.  The extra blank lines all disappeared, `.Length` gives the expected value, and `-match` works!  If you change your comment to an answer I'll accept it as the valid answer.

Comment: Try `[Console]::OutputEncoding = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode` before running `wsl`